# Redirect with URL editing? (remove some 'GET' data)

Tags: php, html, http, redirect, get

Right now there is a page redirection using

> header("Location: {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}");

but the URL that the page is redirecting to is something like:

```
http://localhost:5110/page.php?1st=2&2nd=140413&3rd=547859
```

how can I remove a part of the URL of the redirection?
the URL should be like :

```
http://localhost:5110/page.php?1st=2&3rd=547859
```

If you have another suggestions for this let me know...
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
$referer = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
parse_str($referer['query'], $query);

unset($query['2nd']); // unset the desired element

$referer['query'] = http_build_query($query);
$url = '';
if (array_key_exists('scheme', $referer)) { $url .= "{$referer['scheme']}://"; }
if (array_key_exists('host', $referer)) { $url .= $referer['host']; }
if (array_key_exists('port', $referer)) { $url .= ":{$referer['port']}"; }
if (array_key_exists('path', $referer)) { $url .= $referer['path']; }
if (array_key_exists('query', $referer)) { $url .= "?{$referer['query']}"; }
if (array_key_exists('fragment', $referer)) { $url .= "#{$referer['fragment']}"; }

header("Location: $url");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ref = explode("?",$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
parse_str($ref[1], $qs);
unset($qs['query param to remove']);
$qs = http_build_query($qs);
$ref = $ref[0].'?'.$qs;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$str = 'http://localhost:5110/page.php?1st=2&2nd=140413&3rd=547859';
    echo remove_qs_key($str,"2nd");

    function remove_qs_key($url, $key) {
        $url = preg_replace('/(?:&|(\?))' . $key . '=[^&]*(?(1)&|)?/i', "$1", $url);
        return $url;
    }
```

Result: `http://localhost:5110/page.php?1st=2&3rd=547859`

Answer (score -1):

```
$server = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; //Returns the server name(localhost:5110)
$file = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; //Returns the script name and path(/page.php)
echo $server.$file //Returns localhost:5110/page.php
```

Comment: OP is using `HTTP_REFERER`